# Editar columna completa jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table id="tabla_autos">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Patente</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>LJ5213</td>
        <td id="id_color">Azul</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td>JK5123</td>
        <td id="id_color" >Amarillo</td><!-- color a reemplazar-->
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td>YH512</td>
        <td id="id_color">cafe</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td>FD6521</td>
        <td id="id_color">Amarillo</td><!-- color a reemplazar-->
        <td>56</td>
    </tr>



</tbody>
</table>
```

Necesito cambiar la columna Color cuando este sea amarillo y remplazarlo con naranja esto es lo que llevo:

```
$("#tabla_autos").find("tbody").find("td").each(function(){ 
   if ($(this).attr("id") == "id_color") {
   $("#id_color").text("Naranjo");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varios problemas ahi!, de partida tienes dos `<tr>` con el mismo id y eso es incorrecto, ademas todos los `<td>` tienen el mismo id que es `id_color`. Te recomiendo que en vez de `id` utilices una clase. Seguido de esto, verifica el `text` para saber cual cambiar. En este caso tu quieres cambiar todos los que tengan *Amarillo* y esto lo puedes hacer `if ($(this).text() == 'Amarillo')`

Y para cambiar el valor puedes utilizar esto :

```js
$("#tabla_autos").find("tbody").find("td").each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "id_color") {
       if ($(this).text() == 'Amarillo') {
           $(this).text("Naranjo");
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla_autos">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Patente</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>LJ5213</td>
        <td class="id_color">Azul</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="2">
        <td>JK5123</td>
        <td class="id_color" >Amarillo</td><!-- color a reemplazar-->
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="3">
        <td>YH512</td>
        <td class="id_color">cafe</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td>FD6521</td>
        <td class="id_color">Amarillo</td><!-- color a reemplazar-->
        <td>56</td>
    </tr>



</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda y la aclaración estimado saludos !